# How to keep DeepPavlov REST API service running on Linux when not logged in

Tags: python, linux, rest, service

I have successfully followed steps at http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/integrations/aws_ec2.html to have a REST API running.

Specifically, as outlined in the steps at the link, I ssh to the Ubuntu server and create and activate a Python 3.6 virtual environment and install DeepPavlov and the dependencies and models as outlined in those steps.

The final step is to run the REST API service with the following format:

```
python -m deeppavlov riseapi <config_path> -p <port>
```

The screen will then state that Uvicorn is running and to press CTRL+C to quit.

At that point I am able to access the API from a browser and it logs HTTP requests to the screen.

But if I end the ssh session, then the API service is no longer running.

How can I:

1. Start the service so that it stays running even after I log out of the server.
2. Capture logging from the service.
3. Determine if the service is running or not and be able to stop/restart the service when desired.

Comment: Hi @VinceL, Could you please show us any attempt from your side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create systemd service ([example with virtualenv and systemd](https://gist.github.com/ricferr/90583f608f0b0ae9c3cf6833be04ab85)). With systemd you can start, stop, restart your service via `systemctl` command, and view logs via `journalctl`.